# How to parse or capture command line arguments passed by user and then i want to send those values to some scheduler

Tags: python

when a user enters some commands to enable or disable service/process,i need to capture that command line arguments entered by the user and i have to send those values to some schedulers in python,can anybody help me on this how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can process simple command line arguments like this:

```
import sys
myargs = sys.argv[1:]
print(myargs)
```

I don't know how your scheduler works, but you can do whatever you want with the items in the list `myargs`.

Demo

```
>> python program.py 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']
```

For more complicated command line tools, consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).